# Unrecognized class name / alias: widget.passwordfield

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In extjs when trying to add xtype:'passwordfield' i'm getting this following error:

```plaintext
Unrecognized class name / alias: widget.passwordfield

Synchronously loading 'widget.passwordfield'; consider adding Ext.require('widget.passwordfield') above Ext.onReady
```

Comment: Which ExtJS version and Toolkit are you using? The password field is a widget exclusive to the modern toolkit

Comment: Maybe you have not defined passwordfield and you are using it.

Comment: I'm new to extjs ,how we can define passwordfield , defining means importing?

Answer (score 2):

According to your tag, you are using ExtJS 4. `passwordfield` is for ExtJS 6+ modern. So, in ExtJS 4 you would use:

```
{
        allowBlank: false,
        fieldLabel: 'User ID',
        name: 'user',
        emptyText: 'user id'
    },
    {
        allowBlank: false,
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        name: 'pass',
        emptyText: 'password',
        inputType: 'password'
    }
```

Check the [Login Form](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#login-form) in the examples (and bookmark that page :-) ).

Comment: I am getting the same error... and I am using version 6.0.2. The docs of this version do have [password field](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.field.Password.html). Could there be any other issue causing this error?

Comment: Hi @eNeM, can you share your code please?

Comment: Thanks for responding... 
I'm using [this code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ng4). 
And this is the error I'm getting: `caught Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: widget.passwordfield`
Additional Info:
    ExtJS version: 6.0.2
    Tomcat Version: 8.5.85

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @eNeM: just remove `inputType` and you are done: `passwordfield` will have you covered. Also, it is good practice to use `itemId` instead of `id`: you will avoid naming collisions. Check tip 6 at https://extjsexamples.blogspot.com/2014/03/top-10-ext-js-development-practices-to.html

Comment: I have updated the [code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ng4). It's still giving the same error. Also I used `id` field and later used `Ext.getCmp` to get the value of the field... but when I replaced `id` with `itemId` the `Ext.getCmp` did not work anymore.

Comment: hi @eNeM, check https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3nga  The fiddle was giving a weird error regarding 'widget.form', so I placed the whole form in an Ext.form.Panel. Notice that I fixed as well the confirmation field. Also, I recommend you to check in the examples the password validation: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/examples/kitchensink/?classic#form-advtypes With it you don't have to use Ext.getCmp, which is kind of deprecated.

Comment: Hi @Arthur, I checked your code and tried it. It seems to work fine in Fiddle but not on my local server. Maybe something is wrong or different with the ExtJS package I was given. Even without the `passwordfield` the UI is totally different even though I have selected the same versions and UI packages. Maybe I'll have to check if the provided UI package has some modifications. Meanwhile, can you check if [this code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3ng4) is correct as I can't get the password to reveal and validation to work here?

Comment: Hi @eNeM, how did you build your app: using Sencha CMD, ext-gen or manually? This can affect how the Ext components are being loaded. The fiddle that you sent is ok, except that it misses the `vtype password` definition. In the examples page, check the tab on the right:  you have to create an extended vtype class, which is handy because you can reuse it in the same or other projects.

Comment: I'm doing it manually, don't know much about building through ext-gen or cmd. Thanks for all the explanations. I recently started using ExtJS so didn't know much about these. I'll look into the example again to fix the password fields. Although I guess I'll have to stick to the 'textfield' with inputType.

Comment: It is worth using CMD or Ext-gen, unless you are building a very simple app. In the class definition, you can try `require: ['Ext.field.Password ']` to see if it helps.